# Getting the latest image tag from ACR Repository

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cli, acr

I need to fetch the latest image tag from Azure Container Registry (ACR) with a bash command in my pipeline and use that tag for container deployment.
Here is what I could find with Azure cli:

```
  $ az acr repository show-tags --name myacr --repository myrepo --top 1
```

However this returns me the oldest tag.

How can I get the latest pushed tag from ACR repo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this doc: [az acr repository show-tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-repository-show-tags) and its parameters description:

> Order the items in the results. Default to alphabetical order of
>   names.

Based on your command, it is ordering by alphabetical order of names since you didn't specify the `--orderby`.

Add the parameter `--orderby time_desc` to make the result ordered by time.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not take into account multiple versions. E.g. if `1.1.1` is published later than `1.2.0` then this will return `1.1.1`. There seems to be no way to return the "highest available version".